# negative regex with xidel + garbage-collect function

Tags: xidel

I currently use this command to extract URLs from a site

```
xidel https://www.website.com --extract "//h1//extract(@href, '.*')[. != '']"
```

This will extract all URLs (.*) but I would like to change this in a way that it would not extract URLs that contain specific strings in their URI path. For example, I would like to extract all URLs, except the ones that contain `-text1-` and `-text2-`

Also, xidel has a function called garbage-collect but it's not clear to me how to use these functions. I could be

```
--extract garbage-collect()
```

or

```
--extract garbage-collect()[0]
```

or

```
x:extract garbage-collect()
```

or

```
x"extract garbage-collect()
```

But these didn't reduce the memory usage when extracting URLs from multiple pages using `--follow`.

Comment: What is the website you're trying to extract these urls from? Or could you show these urls?

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this old question. It looks like OP's account is suspended, so I hope the following answer will be helpful for other users.

Let's assume *'test.htm'* :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span class="a-text1-u">1</span>
    <span class="b-text2-v">2</span>
    <span class="c-text3-w">3</span>
    <span class="d-text4-x">4</span>
    <span class="e-text5-y">5</span>
    <span class="f-text6-z">6</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

To extract all "class"-nodes, except the ones that contain "-text1-" and "-text2-":

```
xidel -s test.htm -e "//span[not(contains(@class,'-text1-') or contains(@class,'-text2-'))]/@class"
#or
xidel -s test.htm -e "//@class[not(contains(.,'-text1-') or contains(.,'-text2-'))]"
c-text3-w
d-text4-x
e-text5-y
f-text6-z
```

> *xidel has a function called garbage-collect but it's not clear to me how to use these functions.*

http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-garbage-collect:

> **x:garbage-collect** (*0 arguments*)
>
> Frees unused memory. Always call it as `garbage-collect()[0]`, or it might garbage collect its own return value
> and crash.

So that would be `-e "garbage-collect()[0]"`.